# How to compare the values in the dictionary with the new values?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary

I have a dictionary variable having two values which I have retrieved from the DB. I need to update the values in the DB and while updating I need to check whether the updated values exists in the dictionary values or not. How can I compare. So far I have done this much. Please help me whether this is right or wrong.

Retrieving the datas from the DB and stoing it in Dictionary variable "DictionaryName"

```
For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    DictionaryName.Add(row("EngMemID").ToString(), row("EngMemEmail").ToString())
Next
```

After this I have to compare it with my mew value.

```
        Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)

        For Each pair In DictionaryName
            If DictionaryName.ContainsKey(newMember.EngMemID) Then
                ---Condition to compare the EmailID's 
                    NotifyOnUpdate(newMember)
                ---
            End If
        Next
```

After comparing the ContainsKey(), how can I compare the old and new Email Id's.

Please help me to compare these two values, from the Dictionary with the new value.

Thanks,

Udhaya S.

Comment: Where does the `newMember`  object come from? And where do you compare your `memberEmailList` dictionary to your other dictionary `DictionaryName` ?

Comment: Sorry, Both the dictionaries are same. I'm suppposed to change the name but I didnt. "newMember" is the updated data that comes from another function where we change the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 Dim oldValue As String
 If memberEmaillList.TryGetValue(EngMemID, oldValue) AndAlso oldValue <> EngMemEmail Then
        NotifyOnUpdate(newMember)
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop all members, you can just use the ContainsKey

```
If memberEmaillList.ContainsKey(newMember.EngMemID) Then
    engMemEmail = memberEmaillList(newMember.EngMemID)

    ' Key exists, engMemEmail is the value attached to the key
Else
    ' Key does not exists
End If
```

Comment: I need the condition as it should first compare Dictionary Key "engmemid" if it is equal, it has to go to the next loop and compare Dictionary value "EmailID" with the updated email id.

Comment: @Udhay you want to compare EmailID with which collection? I don't see it stored anywhere. Are you talking about engMemEmail?

Comment: In one function, we have the dictionary where we save the key and value as EngMemID and EmailID which comes from the DB. In another function we have newmember.Engmemid and newmember.emailid which is the updated value. First I need to compare the Dictionary.key(EngMemID) with newmember.engmemid and then with dictionary.value(EmailID) with newmember.email Id.

Comment: If you store it was Dictionary(EngMemID, EmailID) like you say, then the value returned by Dictionary(EngMemID) will be the EmailID. In the example I have, engMemEmail should be the email id.

Answer (score 0):

This is C#

```
if(memberEmaillList.ContainsKey(newMember.EngMemID))
{
     if(string.comare(memberEmaillList[newMember.EngMemID],newMember.EmailAddress,true) == 0))
     {
        //have match
     }
     else 
     {
        //no match
     }
}
```